# Visual Studio Code: toggle between write/insert mode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I toggle between write/insert mode.

- Insert mode: push characters away.
- Write mode: override existing characters.

Comment: AFAIK VSC has no overwrite mode, I use VSC for years and never had the need for overwrite

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an extension called [Overtype](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DrMerfy.overtype) that achieves this.  It works simply by pressing the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key just like many other applications.  You can also toggle the modes using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.